# Firefox extension to close the Find Bar when clicking anywhere on the page

Tags: firefox, search, text-search

Can anyone recommend a Firefox extension that will close the Find Bar when the user clicks anywhere on the page?

Recommendations for gratis or commercial extensions are welcome.

Smaller and simpler extensions are preferred, but all answers are encouraged.

Comment: It's probably easier to just hit `Esc`.

Comment: @user2428118 Thanks.  I'm looking for a quick method that uses the pointing device.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a built-in function for that called “Quick Find”. Simply hit <kbd>/</kbd> when the browser focus is on any part of the web page that does not allow text input.

The downside of this method is that you can't use the *Previous*/*Next* buttons that are present on the full “Find” bar.

Alternatively, you can use the full find bar and hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> when done.